# OrchardCMS Custom Forms and lookup fields

Tags: orchardcms

I can create custom form with Orchard Custom forms Module based on a Content Type.
Also i can add Enumerable field to the Content Type to show as combo box in created custom form.
But i can set list items of the enumerable field statically only.
How can i set this items based on result of a projection query or fill the combo box by any content items of a special content type dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't out of the box.

You could write your own module that provided a query driven combo field, but if you've not written a module before then you might want to start with writing a more simple field module first.

You might find the following useful:

- [Creating a custom field tutorial](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-a-custom-field-type)

I'd also look at the Orchard Source code for the projection module to see how they use queries.